# Minimum number of coins to make up an amount using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, optimization

The problem is the popular one to illustrate Dynamic Programming, which is as follows. We have unlimited coins of each of the denominations 1, 3, and 5. We want the minimum number of coins to get the amount N.

I am aware of the Dynamic Programming method where we build up a solution from the base case(s). But I wanted to see how to write a purely recursive solution. I am able to work it out easily by hand for N = 11 and denominations = [1,3,5]. But for some reason I am unable to make the following work.

```
    def minNumberOfCoins(amount, denominations):
        if amount <= 0:
            return(0)
        if amount in denominations:
            return(1)
        else:
            listToExamine = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, map(lambda x: amount - x, denominations)))
            print(listToExamine)
            minVal = min(listToExamine, key=lambda x: 1 + minNumberOfCoins(x, denominations))
            return(minVal)
```

As far as I can tell, the logic is identical to what I worked out on paper. Is there some nuance in Python's recursion I am not aware of, or is there something subtle I have been missing? Thank you!

Comment: While not relevant to your question, but idiomatic python uses `snake_case` as opposed to `camelCase`.

Comment: Note your solution doesn’t work: `minNumberOfCoins(10, [1, 5, 6])` returns 5 instead of 2. It also raises an exception on `minNumberOfCoins(1, [2])`.

Comment: bfontaine, yes, of course, I noticed it does not work because I worked it out on paper first. I was wondering what I missed when writing the code. I will go over John Gordon's to understand what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation seems more straightforward:

```
def minNumberOfCoins(amount, denominations):

    if amount <= 0:
        return(0)

    if amount in denominations:
        return(1)

    for d in sorted(denominations, reverse=True):
        if d <= amount:
            return 1 + minNumberOfCoins(amount - d, denominations)
```

Comment: Note this will return `None` if called as `minNumberOfCoins(1, [2])`. It’ll also return `5` instead of `2` if called as `minNumberOfCoins(10, [1, 5, 6])` (6+1+1+1+1 instead of 5+5). Edit: OP’s code will raise an exception on the first case and fail as well on the second case.

Comment: What ought to be the result for `(1, [2])`?

Comment: Well I pointed this as an issue but you’re right to return `None` on `(1, [2])`. My bad.

Comment: IIRC, this was almost the first code I wrote and then modified to get to the one I posted.

Answer (score 1):

More readable approach. You should not mix `map` or `filter` with lambdas so much. Conditional comprehensions and generators are usually the better choice:

```
def min_coins(amount, denominations):
    # these two base cases seem to cover more edge cases correctly
    if amount < 0:
        return None
    if amount == 0:
        return 0
    tries = (min_coins(amount-d, denominations) for d in denominations)
    try:
        return 1 + min(t for t in tries if t is not None)
    except ValueError:  # the generator in min produces no values
        return None   

min_coins(11, [1,3,5])
# 3
```

Comment: You could add a slight optimization by using a `for` loop and breaking it once one of the tries return `0`. That would also allow you to remove the `try`/`except`.

Comment: @bfontaine Yeah, I thought about that, too. But I wanted to keep it as readable as possible. If you go for performance, you'd choose a different algorithm to begin with.